# Android - Como acessar uma Activity através de uma Papplet?

Tags: java, android, mobile, java-processing

Possuo uma classe com `extends PApplet` e quero migrar dela para outra com  `extends Activity`

Tentei através de uma `Intent` mas não consegui.

## Corpo da classe PApplet:

```
public class CamMain extends PApplet {

    public void setup() {
        //ESCOPO . . .
    }

    public void draw() {
        //ESCOPO . . .
    }

    public void onCameraPreviewEvent() {
        //ESCOPO. . .
    }

    public void mousePressed() {
        //ESCOPO . . .
    }

    public void teste(){
        // CRIEI PRA TESTAR MIGRAÇÃO POR INTENT, MAS NÃO FUNCIONOU. . .
        //Intent intent = new Intent(this, Teste.class);
        //startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

A PApplet é chamada por uma Activity como mostra o exemplo abaixo

## Activity que chama a PApplet:

```
package processing.test.camMain;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.FrameLayout;
import android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams;
import  android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import processing.core.PApplet;
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    PApplet fragment;
    private static final String MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG = "main_fragment";
    int viewId = 0x1000;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Window window = getWindow();
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN);
        window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        FrameLayout frame = new FrameLayout(this);
        frame.setId(viewId);
        setContentView(frame, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            fragment = new CamMain();
            FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            ft.add(frame.getId(), fragment, MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG).commit();
        } else {
            fragment = (PApplet) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(MAIN_FRAGMENT_TAG);
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        fragment.onBackPressed();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

Comment: O que esse construtor espera é um `context`. Sem ver o resto da classe que contém esse código, não dá pra saber se era pra dar certo. Mostre o resto da classe, por favor.

Comment: Olá, Coloquei o corpo do resto na pergunta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui desta forma:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getActivity(), Teste.class);
try {
    this.finalize();
} catch (Throwable throwable) {
    throwable.printStackTrace();
}
this.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Fala Cristian,

Você tentou com o **startIntent**? exemplo:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Teste.class);
startIntent(intent);
```

Abraços.

Comment: Tentei mas ele não aceita. Quando coloco startActivity(intent), ele não apresenta erros mas, ali no Intent intent = new Intent(this, Teste.class); nos parametros ele apresenta erro. no lugar do this ja tentei colocar o nome da classe.this também mas ele não aceita.